# Website does not get displayed when using IP adress from lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, http

I recently switched my domain to a new ISP and bought a webhosting package.
After checking the IP of my server using who.is, I noticed, that my website can not be viewed directly using the IP.

Instead there was a offer by my ISP. Can someone tell me what function prohibits me from viewing my website directly? What did they setup?

Comment: You are using a shared webhosting package, and the IP address is shared between hundreds, perhaps thousands of different websites.

Answer (score 2):

Usually web hosting provider do something called [Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) where a single server with a single IP address provides hosting for multiple websites. The reason why you don't see your website when you try using the IP address directly is because it's one out of many hosted behind that particular IP address.